# adding items to listview as a listitem

Tags: android

Hi can someone please help me I am trying to create a messaging type app when 'addButton is clicked I want it to go to add this to my existing listview as an item - I've researched how to do this and have tried applying this to my code unsuccessfully. My problem line is

convoItems.add(editText.getText().toString());

I get this error

```
add in ArrayList cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
```

Here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
    public class ConversationView extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation_view);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String thread = intent.getStringExtra("threadId");

        threadId = Integer.parseInt(thread);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.write_a_message);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_message_button);

        final ListView convoListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.conversationListView);

        final ArrayList<ConversationItem> convoItems = this.GetItems(threadId);

        final ConversionAdapter convoAdapter = new ConversionAdapter
                (this, R.layout.conversation_list_item, convoItems);

        convoListView.setAdapter(convoAdapter);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                convoItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                convoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        convoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(ConversationView.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: You need to update your adapter by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Hi sorry I've done that - I just posted my code

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you have convoItems, that is a ArrayList of ConversationItem and you are trying to add a String type (editText.getText().toString()), no?

Comment: the error i get is add in ArrayList cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes I think that is probably right Lucas but I'm not sure how I could fix this to work for my app

Comment: You need to include any errors in your post so it's clear what's going on. According to your post, it sounds like you aren't getting any errors but the items just aren't showing

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, I have added the error i get on the line of code 'convoItems.add(editText.getText().toString());'

Comment: @codeMagic would you mind explaining this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [LucasT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514286/lucas-t) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594217/adding-items-to-listview-as-a-listitem/28594584#comment45495153_28594217)...

The error is telling you that you can't add an item of type `String` to the `ArrayList` because the list is instantiated with the type `ConversationItem` here

```
final ArrayList<ConversationItem> convoItems = this.GetItems(threadId);
```

So you need to add that type of an `Object`. But you are trying to add a `String` with

```
convoItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
```

In your `ConversationItem` you need to pass whatever you need to create that `Object` and add *that* to your list. I can't see that class so I can't say for sure how to do it but you should be able to figure out how to create an `ConversationItem` object.

It would be something like you are doing in `GetItems()` with

```
new ConversationItem(1, 1, "Bob Doe", DateTime.now(), "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a mauris tincidunt, vehicula elit atr."));
```

But I don't know exactly what data you want to use to create it. That is up to you.

**Example**

```
convos.add(new ConversationItem(1, 1, "Bob Doe", DateTime.now(), editText.getText().toString(), 
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a mauris tincidunt, vehicula elit atr."));
```

Comment: i wanted to create the message part (Lorem ipsum text) with whatever I pass through the edittext field?

Comment: Right, so you will still need to create an instance of `ConversationItem` and pass that text as the parameter for your message `param` of that object.

Comment: Thank you for your help I understand this better now.